# Error in predict.randomForest

Tags: r

I was hoping someone would be able to help me out with an issue I am having with the prediction function of the randomForest package in R. I keep getting the same error when I try to predict my test data:

Here's my code so far:

```
extractFeatures <- function(RCdata) {
 features                     <- c(4, 9:13, 17:20)
 fea                          <- RCdata[, features]
 fea$Week                     <- as.factor(fea$Week)
 fea$Age_Range                <- as.factor(fea$Age_Range)
 fea$Race                     <- as.factor(fea$Race)
 fea$Referral_Source          <- as.factor(fea$Referral_Source)
 fea$Referral_Source_Category <- as.factor(fea$Referral_Source_Category)
 fea$Rehire                   <- as.factor(fea$Rehire)
 fea$CLFPR_.HS                <- as.factor(fea$CLFPR_.HS)
 fea$CLFPR_HS                 <- as.factor(fea$CLFPR_HS)
 fea$Job_Openings             <- as.factor(fea$Job_Openings)
 fea$Turnover                 <- as.factor(fea$Turnover)
 return(fea)
 }

gp       <- runif(nrow(RCdata))
RCdata   <- RCdata[order(gp), ]
train    <- RCdata[1:4600, ]
test     <- RCdata[4601:6149, ]

rf <- randomForest(extractFeatures(train), suppressWarnings(as.factor(train$disposition_category)), ntree=100, importance=TRUE)
    testpredict <- predict(rf, extractFeatures(test))
    "Error in predict.randomForest(rf, extractFeatures(test)) : 
          Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data."
```

I have tried adding in the following line to the code, and still receive the same error:

```
testpredict <- predict(rf, extractFeatures(test), type="prob")
```

I found the source of the error being the fact that the training data has a level or two that is not found in the test data. So when I tried another suggestion I found online to adjust the levels of the test data to that of the training data, I keep getting NULL values in the fields I am using in both the training and test sets.

```
levels(test$Referral)
NULL
```

I can see the levels when I use the function, however.

```
levels(as.factor(test$Referral))
```

So then I tried the same suggestion I found online with adjusting the levels of the test to equal that of the training data using the following function and received an error:

```
levels(as.factor(test$Referral)) -> levels(as.factor(train$Referral))
Error in `levels<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, value = c(...  : 
  number of levels differs
```

I am sure there is something simple I am missing (I am still very new to R), so any insight you can provide would be unbelievably helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Are there factor levels in the test data that are not in the training data ?  For example, if you have vectors `train <- c('a', 'b', 'c')` and `test <- c('b', 'c', 'd'))`, both have values unique to themselves ('a' and 'd'). Do you have this situation ?  You could create the levels with something like `my_levels <- unique(c(train$Referral, test$Referral))`

Comment: It is hard to follow what you are trying to do with out being able to run the code or seeing the solutions you are referencing, but you if you want to change the levels on a factor you do it by `test$Referral <- factor(test$Referral, levels = levels(train$Referral))`

Comment: I have dealt with this error about 1,000 times. Sometimes it is simple like level issues as described above, sometimes it's something totally different. People who don't know think it's simple user error. Can you share your data? If not and the above solutions don't work make sure you don't have any NA factor levels. Even with `addNA` this predict method won't work with them. Verify also if you get this error when trying to predict on the training dataset (if so, it's the NA factor level issue or another less obvious one).

Comment: Really appreciate everyone's input on this! 

So a few things: 
1) I do not get the same error when I run with the training data
2) I posted the code above so you can follow where I was prior to the code I originally posted
3) The two suggestions from @steveb and Barker don't seem to work either. 
The structure of the data is the same for both sets of data from a column/field standpoint and the structure of each column. I am new to how to deal with values that appear in a field for training data that do not appear in the test data. I guess that's where I am at now
Thanks!

Comment: At this point you really need to share your data (`dput`) or reproduce the problem with built-in / public data. There are good tips on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve