# Error predict.randomForest, factor levels

Tags: r, random-forest, levels

I have been plugging away on this for days without success.  I've reviewed similar threads ([Error in predict.randomForest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986119/error-in-predict-randomforest)) but nothing seems to help.  I am trying to develop a model that examines how seeding rate (Rx) impacts yield.

I think I need to figure out how to make the factor levels of my 
test data match my training data because I get this error:

```
Error in predict.randomForest(randFor.mod, newdata = pred.27k) : 
New factor levels not present in the training data
```

I subset my training data (pred.sub) from the full data (pred.all) such that I only consider Yields that have values, the test data has Yields with NA.

```
pred.sub<-subset(pred.all, !(is.na(pred.all$Yield)))
```

Model runs fine on the training data.

However, a side step is that I need to create separate dataframes for each seeding rate:

```
pred.27k<-pred.all
pred.27k$Rx<-27000
pred.27k$Rx<-factor(pred.27k$Rx, c(27000, 32000, 37000, 42000))

pred.32k<-pred.all
pred.32k$Rx<-32000
pred.32k$Rx<-factor(pred.32k$Rx, c(27000, 32000, 37000, 42000))

pred.37k<-pred.all
pred.37k$Rx<-37000
pred.37k$Rx<-factor(pred.37k$Rx, c(27000, 32000, 37000, 42000))

pred.42k<-pred.all
pred.42k$Rx<-42000
pred.42k$Rx<-factor(pred.42k$Rx, c(27000, 32000, 37000, 42000))
```

I checked pred.all, pred.sub, and pred.27k - pred.42k and Rx is a factor in each data set and has 4 levels (27000 - 42000).

I have imputed any missing data for any predictor variable.

Ironically, I have used this code in the past without issue.

Given Rx is a factor with 4 levels across the full dataset (pred.all), the training data (pred.sub), and the test data (pred.27k - pred.42k) I am not sure what else to do.  I have tried tweaks to the code when setting the levels for pred.27k - pred.42k, but nothing works.

One clue may be that pred.sub$Rx and pred.all$Rx have 4 levels with decimals (27000.0005), but pred.27k$Rx has 4 levels that are the assigned whole number (27000).

Comment: Could you provide random 20 rows of train and test data with `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with a colleague who gave me a quick fix that works:

```
pred.all$Rx<-factor(round(as.numeric(as.character(pred.all$Rx))))
```

Where pred.all is the complete dataset.  This rounded any values in the test/training data to match the levels here:

```
pred.27k<-pred.all
pred.27k$Rx<-27000
pred.27k$Rx<-factor(pred.27k$Rx, c(27000, 32000, 37000, 42000))

pred.32k<-pred.all
pred.32k$Rx<-32000
pred.32k$Rx<-factor(pred.32k$Rx, c(27000, 32000, 37000, 42000))

pred.37k<-pred.all
pred.37k$Rx<-37000
pred.37k$Rx<-factor(pred.37k$Rx, c(27000, 32000, 37000, 42000))

pred.42k<-pred.all
pred.42k$Rx<-42000
pred.42k$Rx<-factor(pred.42k$Rx, c(27000, 32000, 37000, 42000))
```

Basically, the levels have to be identical, the small decimal mismatch was the issue.  Problem solved.  After the fact, now it seems simple...